# (nautilus:18063): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0 not connect: Connection refused

Tags: 17.10, gksudo

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 and I found that it is no longer accepting password in the `gksudo nautilus` password window. I get this error instead

```
(nautilus:18063): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
:0 not connect: Connection refused
```